# How to change logback log level dynamically in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-cloud

I have a Spring boot application which use logback.xml for logging configurations.I am looking for options to dynamically change log level.
For instance if I have deployed an app with loglevel as ERROR,Let say I want to change this to INFO but I don't want to redeploy/restart my JVM.

Is there any possibility we can configure logback.xml like config server to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure Logback to [Automatically reloading configuration file upon modification](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#autoScan)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is quite possible. Expose a rest endpoint where you supply the className and log level. With slf4j you can get the LoggerContext and change the level.

```
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    context.getLogger(className).setLevel(Level.valueOf(level));
```

Apache Commons logging and others have similar features.

Comment: plus If you need to set the log level globally for all classes [for root], you can by  `context.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME).setLevel(Level.valueOf(level));`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using spring cloud then you can have this in your yml file

```
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
```

Then you can change it and refresh the configuration using actuator refresh to fetch new configuration changes no need to restart the service.

Also if you need some sort of UI to do this stuff you can explore the [Spring-cloud-dashboard](https://github.com/VanRoy/spring-cloud-dashboard) It is pretty cool and uses the features from the actuator to do and show you a lot of stuff not only changing log levels.